# Code First and Model First in the same project?

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I have two databases that I am accessing. The first is against a contact database which I connected to using EF Model First; creating the edmx. I have since begun to learn the virtue of CODE First when working with Entity Framework, so I decided I would, in the same project, write the Product database using Code First techniques, allowing the database to be generated from the code I am writing.

Everything compiles fine. The problem occurs when I hit my harness and it attempts to create the Product database and retreive a list of values from one of the tables...

I get the folowing error "*Could not find the conceptual model type for 'Core.Data.Account'*", when I attempt to enumerate the ProductLines property (Line3 below).

```
1.    using (var ctx = new ProductDb())
2.    {
3.        var lines = ctx.ProductLines.ToList();
4.        this.litOne.Text = lines.Count.ToString();
5.    }
```

After some research it appears that this message may be occuring because of multiple entities with the same name (regardless of namespace), however there is nothing in the ProductDb context with the name "Account".

There is a class in the OTHER context created by the Model First approach named "Account". But how/why would that make a difference? They each point to different databases i.e. different connection strings. Why would the ProductDb be attempting to create a table called Account, when it should be completely unaware of it's exstence?

thoughts?

Thank you as always!,
- G

Answer (score 1):

I bumped into the same problem, but the other way around: first a DbContext + generated database and then generated an edmx off the database (just for a little presentation). It appeared to be a restriction in EF: [EF currently has a restriction that POCO classes can't be loaded from an assembly that contains classes with the EF attributes](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adonetefx/thread/b87815ff-6569-4559-8268-7ae6433b8aa8).

The only thing you can do for now is keep the contexts in separate assemblies.